# breaking from a for look inside a reucrsive function

Tags: javascript

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6s1vouv/).
I am bit stuck with why the loop does not break the way I intended.

`input` is an object, indexed with some kind of id. And the values are the children ids. so, I am trying to filter out (here it is hard coded as `d`) a node and its children. For example, for `d`, there is only one child, `h`. so, I was expecting an output `['d', 'h']`. This is because, once the filter condition met (`c === 'd'`), it discards all previous value, and just recurse to its children (only `h`) in this case. Once the recursion to children finished, the break should terminate the for loop. but as I see from the output, the for loop doesn't breaks and continues with (`c` -> `g`). How to make this so once the filter met, it only output the node and all its children `['d', 'h']` in this case.

```
const input = {
  a: ['b', 'c'],
  b: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  c: ['g'],
  d: ['h'],
}
let data = [];
const recur = (d) => {
  const ch = input[d]
  if (!ch) {
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    console.log(data)
    const c = ch[i]
    data.push(c)
    if (c === 'd') {
      data = [c];
      console.log("reset data", data)
      recur(c)
      break
    }
    recur(c)
  }
}

recur('a')
console.log("end: ", data)
```

output: `end:  ["d", "h", "c", "g"]`

Comment: It would help if you explain the _intended behaviour_

Comment: use a while statement, or [].forEach() instead

Comment: @Supersharp out of curiosity, what is wrong with for loop. I thought break works with `for`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with break in loop. But with your algorithm: you break form the second recursive loop but never from the first one.

Comment: First things first, stop using that global `data` array immediately. Use a local variable, and `return` its value. Now rethink your algorithm.

Comment: @Supersharp `while` or `forEach` make no sense here

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I was thinking the same as it is cleaner, but left it out as an improvement :-) but now looks like a bug is caused by that, and will rewrite to output an array from recur fn.

Comment: @Bergi please see my attempt, and  let me know if a strikingly easy way!

Comment: @bsr Looks good to me for a combined function. It might be easier though to separate the functionality in a `find` function that returns the found element (and its children?) or nothing (or true/false) and a `descendants` function that unconditionally collects all children recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. https://jsfiddle.net/j6s1vouv/4/ There need a way to inform the parent that, the filter is met and should skip the sibling iteration.

```
const input = {
  a: ['b', 'c'],
  b: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  c: ['g'],
  d: ['h'],
}
const recur = (d) => {
  const ch = input[d]
  if (!ch) {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  }

  let out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    const c = ch[i]
    const x = recur(c)
    if (x.skip) { // if any of the child met filter
      return x
    }

    if (c === 'd') { // current id met filter
      return {
        data: [c].concat(x.data),
        skip: true
      }
    }

    out = out.concat([c], x.data)
  }
  return {
    data: out
  }
}


console.log("end: ", recur('a').data)
```